# svelte kit routing and naming covention problem

Tags: javascript, deployment, web-applications, sveltekit, svelte-3

when i create a new svelte kit project the default file is +page.svelte if i change the name it wont render and if i try to link to other svelte file it wont work

```
<script>
  import { goto } from '$app/navigation';

  function handleMissionClick() {
    goto('/game/Mission');
  }
</script>

<div class="grid">

      <button class="button" on:click={handleMissionClick}>Mission</button>

</div>
for example when i click on mission it returns error 404 although game/mission path exists
```

i tried searching for a way search where +page is configured so i can add other files as configurations but it didnt work

Comment: Is it `/game/Mission` or `game/mission`? Instead of `goto` a normal link would also work https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/link-options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SvelteKit, only `+page.svelte` is recognized as a page by the router.
You cannot use differently-named svelte files as pages. Instead, place a `+page.svelte` in a folder with the desired name of the route.

For example, you could use the following routes structure to have a home page and a page for the mission game:

```
/src/routes
    +page.svelte
    /game
        /Mission
            +page.svelte
```

I recommend that you familiarize yourself with the Routing documentation for SvelteKit: https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing. The docs do a good job of explaining everything you can do with the router, including how to create pages.

Comment: i get it but the Mission+page.svelte you mentioned will be a name of the file in routes/game or will Mission be an extra folder inside the game folder so i know the +page is related?

Comment: like for example routes/game/Mission/+page.svelte or routes/game/Mission+page.svelte

Comment: it seems in the code you provided that the game folder is inside the main +page.svelte file

Comment: Yes, if you want a page to exist at `/game/Mission`, you should put the `+page.svelte` inside the Mission folder, which should then be inside the game folder. I'll edit my answer to make that more clear.

Comment: It's a bit disappointing they couldn't allow us to use same directory names. For example ```missions/mission.svelte```